# Using "above" before or after a word

Tags: adverbs, sentence-structure

> Considering **the discussion above**, we aim to provide a wrapper construction method ....

vs.

> Considering **the above discussion**, we aim to provide a wrapper construction method ....

I know in #2 "above" is used as an adjective, what about #1? what is its role?

Which is more common?

Answer (score 1):

"Above" is an **adverb** in **#1**. In your sentences, you are saying that the discussion is **above *something***. However, it is **implied** that you are referring to wherever your sentence is:

> Considering the discussion above **(the body of text in which this sentence is located)**, we aim to provide a wrapper construction method…

(In that example, "above" is being used as a preposition.)
Obviously, you would never say that, but that is the meaning you're trying to convey. In response to the question of which is more common, I would say **#2**.  Either is correct, but **#2** sounds more formal.

Comment: Thanks, but in #2 it appears before a noun, then I guess it is an adjective there.

Comment: @Ahmad Sorry about that, it actually is being used as an adjective in #2. It is still a preposition in number 1, though. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I see  two roles for it in the dictionary, adverb and adjective, then it may be an adverb in #1, somethings like "here", "there"...., though I am not sure, because as you said it can be used like a preposition to relate two nouns.

Comment: @Ahmad Hmm. Dictionaries do say that above in #1 is an adverb. Looks like I was incorrect for both sentences!